# Fetch all records with child tables which have many to many relationship using LINQ

Tags: mysql, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have Table A with Columns ID and Name. Table B is child table with one to many Relationship with Table A. I have Table C which has one to many relationship with Table B. I want to fetch all records of Table A along with related table B data and Table C data.

What is the best approach for doing this in LINQ to SQL using entity framework. Do I need to write separate queries.
Or is it possible to fetch in single Query transaction.

I have tried including the Table B when I select Table A. But to select Table C data, do I need to loop through Table B or is it possible with direct LINQ query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using entity framework then you can use the `.Include()` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

It's hard to give an example without knowing your actual situation but your query might lok something like this:

```
var data = context.TableA.Include("TableB");
```

And if you wanted TableC also then...

```
var data = context.TableA.Include("TableB.TableC");
```